# Qt5 hash functions do not return the same hash on Windows 7 and Windows10

Tags: c++

I want to hash a given string and later verify the hash code across multiple platforms and operating systems. I just made this simple function in Qt 5.12. I am using Windows 10 64 bit as development machine.

```
void hashCheckFunction(QString input)
{

    QByteArray ba;
    const char *str =   input.toStdString().c_str();
    ba.append(str);

    QByteArray md5Ba=QCryptographicHash::hash(ba,QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex();
    QString md5hash(md5Ba);
    qDebug()<<"MD5 : "<<md5hash;

    QByteArray shaBa=QCryptographicHash::hash(ba,QCryptographicHash::Sha256).toHex();
    QString sha256hash(shaBa);
    qDebug()<<"SHA 256 : "<<sha256hash;
}
```

This is how I use the function.

```
hashCheckFunction("JXTSLRCQKFLBZBTWRRRR0.190hello world!cute");
```

**Output on Windows 7:**

MD5 : 7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29

SHA256 : 559aead08264d5795d3909718cdd05abd49572e84fe55590eef31a88a08fdffd

**Output on Windows 10:**

MD5 : 4eb30b25e43174eabe0e13426716ef40

SHA256 : a5e37a6bfb24ca261cfa91ed5fb73a89a652164c43cd4f7a99147d18d4508eaf

**Note:**

1. Output on Windows 10 is correct because Windows 10 output is same as
   my PHP script generates which runs on a Linux server. I have
   verified that Windows 10 generated hash is same as PHP on Linux
   server. I did so just to check which one is correct.
2. For many string inputs the output on Windows 7 and Windows 10 is also same. The
   above string example is a specific case in which the same function
   generates different hash codes.

**Question:**
Why do I not get the same hash similar to Windows 10 on Windows 7 machine? What is the solution?

Comment: Have you checked that the byte arrays contain the same data?

Comment: Please print out the content of your `input` string in the function too. How do you call `hashCheckFunction()` function?

Comment: `input.toStdString().c_str()` only survives as long as the temporary `std::string`. What you do afterwards depends on this string surviving, which is undefined behavior. Use `input.toUtf8()` instead to directly get a `QByteArray`.

Comment: Why don't you just do `ba.append(input);` ?

Comment: @Botje: Please don't post answers as comments; this question now incorrectly appears unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.toStdString()` constructs a temporary `std::string` that is only guaranteed to survive for the duration of the statement it is in.
You then take the address of this temporary variable using `.c_str()` and pass it to `ba.append()`.

Inbetween these two events, the temporary string is freed and anything could happen to the just-freed memory. If it works on Windows 7, it is entirely by accident.

A more structural solution is to construct the `QByteArray` directly as follows:

```
QByteArray ba = input.toUtf8();
```

This will still create a temporary object, but the `QByteArray` assignment operator will ensure the memory is copied into `ba` (or moved, depending on your version of Qt).